# OriginalDesiredAccess manipulation in ring0

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, hook, wdm

Simple question. I wrote driver (WDM) which hook itself with callback's and intercept virtual memory functions, terminate, suspend end etc (i want to build little self defense). And.. if i try to terminate my app via standard application (without admin rights) - i can't do that, but if i try same thing via application with debug privileges - program successfully terminating. Where my mistake?

Method do detect WriteMemoryProcess:

```
if ((OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.OriginalDesiredAccess & PROCESS_VM_WRITE) == PROCESS_VM_WRITE)
{
    OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess &= ~PROCESS_VM_WRITE;
}
```

Callback registration:

```
RegisterOperation.ObjectType = PsProcessType;
RegisterOperation.Operations = OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE;
RegisterOperation.PreOperation = ObjectPreCallback;
RegisterOperation.PostOperation = ObjectPostCallback;
RegisterCallBack.Version = OB_FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION;
RegisterCallBack.OperationRegistrationCount = registrationCount;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&Altitude, L"XXXXXXX");
RegisterCallBack.Altitude = Altitude;
RegisterCallBack.RegistrationContext = &RegistrationContext;
RegisterCallBack.OperationRegistration = &RegisterOperation;
```

Thanks for advice!